# Can a soul exist without its spirit?

Tags: genesis, hebrews

To engage in this question, you need to assume the tripartite nature of man. Arguing against that will be a different question which you are welcome to make by initiating a separate posting. Assuming the tripartite nature of man does not automatically imply that you believe in it.

> King James Bible Genesis 2:7
> And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living **soul**.

> Hebrews 4:12
> For the word of God is quick, and powerful, and sharper than any twoedged sword, piercing even to the dividing asunder of soul and spirit, and of the joints and marrow, and is a discerner of the thoughts and intents of the heart.

Apparently spirit and soul can be put together and are distinct. Can a soul exist independently without its associated spirit?

Comment: The word of God _discerns_ . . .  _between_ the two. It does not _separate_ the two.

Comment: Good point. I updated.

Comment: First, you need to define a soul! (biblically) The spirit is the easy bit :) and which/whose spirit?

Comment: What evidence is there that a soul "has" a spirit?

Comment: I did not say that a soul has a spirit or wish to imply that a soul 'has" a spirit but that they form a pair.

Comment: In attempting to answer the question, I’d like to respond as follow: man is created in the image of God, the Creator and therefore a Father of all (Deut. 32:6; Mal. 2:10; Eph. 3:14-15). The core of the inward man is the soul/living (spiritual) being (Gen.2:7) having a faculty to produce word (thought/idea conveyed through spoken word) and a breath of life. The outward man is the flesh which is an earthly house or a temporary tent according to apostle Paul (Romans 7:22; 2 Cor. 4:26; 5:10). May God’s grace be with all truth searching and loving souls all over the world. God bless all!

Comment: Man is a spirit. Man is not a soul. Man possesses a soul. (And these are ‘housed’ in a body,). Gen 2 simply says that Man (spirit/soul) was put into a physical body, so he could Live and express dominion on the earth.

Comment: In the Hebrew quotation you give, there is a tetra-partite division, I guess: body, soul, spirit and heart.

Comment: A  soul is an immaterial thing. Not physical. And it is immortal. It cannot die. _The body without the spirit is dead_, it is written. But it is never said in scripture that a soul without its spirit is dead. They are one.

Comment: "Can a soul exist independently without its associated spirit?" This is a theological question, not a textual question, which belongs at [christianity.se]. This question should not be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

**Can a soul exist without its spirit?**

In short to your question, the answer is  NO. Why?

**So what do the terms  "soul" and spirit really mean?**

THE SOUL WHAT IS IT?

The belief that something immaterial, intangible or immortal that leaves the body on death is a Platonic philosophical speculation or theological bias, and it is nowhere to be found in scriptures.

The Bible helps us understand what a soul is. It is used 1/ For people, 2/ animals. 3/ the life a person or an animal has.  **For this question, only in the sense, 1/for people will be considered.**

For people

Genesis 2:7  (NASB)

> " Then the Lord God formed man of dust from the ground, and breathed
> into his nostrils the breath of life; **and man became a living being."**

Footnotes NASB: Genesis 2:7 **Lit "soul"**

Genesis 2:7  (KJV)

> 7 And the Lord God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed
> into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became **a living soul.**

**Notice KJV-a living soul,  NASB -a living being**

**People:** In Noah's day "In the ark a few, that is eight souls, were delivered  safely through water." Here the word souls clearly stands for people, Noah, his wife, his three sons, and their wives.

1 Peter 3:20  (NET Bible)

> 20 After they were disobedient long ago when God patiently waited[b]
> in the days of Noah as an ark was being constructed. In the ark a few,
> that is eight souls, were delivered through water.

Thus the explanation of what a human soul is may be reduced to this simple, unmysterious "soul equation"

**human soul = body + breath of life from God.**

**The spirit what is it ?**

Many people believe that "spirit” is just another word for "soul. However, that is not the case. The Bible makes clear that "spirit" and "soul" refer to two different things. How do they differ?

The scriptures help us clarify those words, for example, read  how  Psalms 104:29 is translated by NASB and the NET Bibles below:

> Psalm 104:29  (NASB)   "You hide Your face, they are dismayed;  **You
> take away their spirit, they expire  And return to their dust."**
>
> Psalm 104:29  (NET Bible) " When you ignore them, they panic.  When
> **you take away their life’s breath, they die and return to dust."**

Also James 2:26  (NASB) states;

26 For just as the body without the spirit is dead, so also faith without works is dead.

Clearly then in these verses above the word "spirit" refers to that which gives life to the body.

Conclusion;

The soul and the spirit are not the same. The body (the human soul) needs the spirit -- the breath of life that brings our body to life. As the Psalmist said, without the spirit, the body (soul) returns to dust.

**Some other verses on the  "soul" and notice how various translations render the verses.**

THE SOUL WHO SINS WILL  DIE.

Ezekiel 18:4 (NASB)

> "Behold, all souls are Mine; the soul of the father as well as the
> soul of the son is Mine. **The soul who sins will die.**"

CAN A SOUL DIE?

Leviticus 24:17-18 (YLT)

> 17 "And when a man smiteth any soul of man, he is certainly put to
> death.18 `And he who smiteth a beast repayeth it, body for body."

Leviticus 24:17-18 (NASB)

17 ‘If a man takes the life of any human being, he shall surely be put to death. 18 The one who [b]takes the life of an animal shall make it good, life for life.

Acts 3:23  (NASB)

> 23" And it will be that every soul that does not heed that prophet
> shall be utterly destroyed from among the people."

Acts 2:23 (ERV)

> 23 "And anyone who refuses to obey that prophet will die, separated
> from God’s people."

Answer (score 2):

The Biblical words for "soul" – Hebrew: nephesh (נפש)/Greek: psyche – have a broader sense of meaning that we generally ascribe to them.

In Genesis 1, we find nephesh (נפש) used of fish (Gen. 1:21) or animals (Gen. 1:24) as well as humanity (Gen. 2:7).

In the Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament (TDOT), it is noted that (נפש) refers to the "individuation of life," as well as the "psychic power, abounding personality, energy that exonerates all gloominess." Additionally, the author (Seebass), summarizes that (נפש) is "a whole person, a figure of joy in life and vitality."

Simply put, a human being doesn't have a soul; they are a soul.

Likewise, Wayne G. Rollins, in his book *Soul and Psyche*, notes that the Greet word psyche (translated “soul” in Heb. 4:12) carries the same broad meaning found in the OT into the New Testament. He writes:

> psyche denotes "the total system of conscious and unconscious life in the human personality."

Humanity is “spirit” + “body” = “soul.”

The passage in question - Gen. 2:7 can be used as an example:

> Then the LORD God formed a man from the **dust of the ground** and breathed into his nostrils the **breath of life**, and the man became a **living being**.

God formed a "body" from the earth and breathed in a "spirit" thus, in combination, creating a living "soul"

Conversely to Genesis 2:7, Ecclesiastes 12:7 tells us:

> and the **dust** returns to the ground it came from, and the **spirit** (רוּחַ) returns to God who gave it.

Finally, James 2:26 tells us that when the spirit separates from the body there is death:

> As the body without the spirit is dead, so faith without deeds is dead.

The connections of (mind, body, spirit, soul) are so complex and intertwined that only God can determine where one ends and the other begins.  The complexity of these connections is such that degradation in them will affect all aspects of our lives.

Since we have a “spirit” - and our spirit exists beyond this physical world - we are by our very nature spiritual beings.

Our spirit communes with God through His Holy Spirit. The Holy Spirit regenerates our spirit.

Likewise, our spirit can atrophy or be affected by dark spiritual forces. A weak spirit leads to an overall weak soul or being.

If spirit and body are disconnected – it would follow that a "soul" no longer exists.

When Jesus died on the cross, he quoted Psalm 31:5,  saying:

> "Father, into your hands, I commit my *spirit*."

Stephen says something similar in the book of Acts:

> While they were stoning him, Stephen prayed, "Lord Jesus, receive my *spirit*."

---

From my experience of doing my own spiritual formation work with a spiritual formation coach, I would divide a human being into “body, mind, spirit.” All of these create a “soul” or “psyche” (in the original/biblical use of the word psyche).

Again, from my own experience, the spirit is the most powerful and directly affects the mind and the body.  Hence, so many of Jesus’ miracles are spiritual in nature but heal the physical and mental manifestations.

Comment: I'd upvote this but really needs more scriptural reference

Comment: Fair enough.  I've included more scripture references above.

Answer (score 1):

Your soul is who you are individually as a person. It is the man in the unregenerated state. An easy way to understand the difference is --
Soul : human being with their animal instincts. Beastly. To fill the belly, selfish, looking out for themselves, survival instincts

Jude verse 10 NASB
10 But these men revile the things which they do not understand; and the things which they know by instinct, like unreasoning animals, by these things they are destroyed.

1 Corinthians 2:14-15: “A soulish man does not receive the things of the Spirit of God, for they are foolishness to him and he is not able to know them because they are discerned spiritually. But the spiritual man discerns all things, but he himself is discerned by no one.”

Spirit : the power of the holy spirit indwelling you to empower you to overcome your animal instincts and live according to God's will.

A soul is  'dead' without the spirit of God because it is the spirit that quickens you and transfers you from death to Life.

So yes, a soul can live ( in the mortal sense) without a spirit, but you are spiritually dead.

Edited to add-
Paul defined what being spiritually dead means :
Eph 2:1-3 KJV - 1 And you hath he quickened, who were dead in trespasses and sins; 2 Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience: 3 Among whom also we all had our conversation in times past in the lusts of our flesh, fulfilling the desires of the flesh and of the mind; and were by nature the children of wrath, even as others.

Comment: +1 That's surprisingly good for a newcomer. Welcome to the scholarly site for Christian Hermeneutics.

Comment: I would agree with @ Tony Chan. Please could you expand on your last paragraph where you say " So yes, a soul can live ( in a mortal sense) without a spirit, but you are spiritually dead.. Help me understand what you mean by" being spiritually dead" Thank you.

Comment: Your Ephesians quote indicates that the those who were previously dead (before being quickened) operated according to the spirit of the prince of the power of the air.  Therefore being dead spiritually is not to be devoid of spirit but to be of wrong spirit.

Comment: Galatians 4:8 Howbeit then, when ye knew  not God,  ye did service unto them which by nature  are no  gods. Meaning it's our human sinful will not a spirit of Satan

Comment: You have confused the spirit of a man (which is part of human nature) and the indwelling Spirit (who is a divine person). The indwelling Spirit of God is in union with the spirit of a man when he is born anew. A soul that is spiritually 'dead' still has the spirit of a man within it (prior to regeneration).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’ve already read “The Spiritual Man” so I won’t go into any of those details here :). Put simply, I think a soul can exist without a spirit (how animals are assumed to live), but I don’t believe *man* can exist without a spirit. God’s breath in man imparted His spirit/life in man - though the English translates to “soul” in KJV, what is really meant is “man became a living soul [with the Spirit of God inside].” That’s why it’s not noted that every animal became a living soul, because even though they were indeed living souls, the breath of God was not in them to impart a spirit. While our spirit’s function became dead/cut off from God because of sin, we always had and will have a spirit (and, a perfected soul one day, too, it seems like).

Answer (score 0):

Since the "soul" and "spirit" here is used in a parallel, isomorphic pair with "joints" and "marrow", it is not plausible to interpret that this "spirit" is divine uncreated Spirit, but, together with soul, this spirit also should be an aspect of human inner, intangible essence, just like joints and marrow are aspects of the human tangible essence.

And surely, this must be the case, for otherwise it will be an illogicality that God's commandment or word is sharper than Holy Spirit, cutting through in the division of Him (the Spirit) and human soul, but nothing can be sharper than Holy Spirit, who is just as "sharp", if we can metaphorically use this epithet, as the Father and the Logos are.

If so, then the spirit of man must be some higher aspect of the soul, perhaps the rational aspect, or that aspect that tells truth from falsity, a human conscience, that can be enlightened by the divine word, divine unmistakable commandment. While "soul" can be that aspect of inner personality that accounts for emotions, emotional thoughts, love, hatred, while "spirit" discerning the meaning of divine commandments is the rudder of our inner essence, that should establish a correct hierarchy between soul's inclinations and direct emotions to rightful paths. For example, if my "soul", i.e. my emotion of love of glory tells me to win olympics, my "spirit" discerning divine truth of things, tells me not to do this with a help of doping and cheating. Perhaps exactly this is that word/commandment of God divides between soul and spirit, that is to say, shows a difference between them.

But the passage does not mean that soul can be thought as a separate essence from the spirit, they can well form one invisible reality's, human character's or heart's different aspects, although Paul does not make it very clear, I guess.

Comment: +1 You may want to read https://www.biblesnet.com/Watchman%20Nee%20The%20Spiritual%20Man%20I.pdf. It agrees with some of your ideas here.

Comment: @TonyChan Thank you! Who is the author of the text from the link?

Comment: 倪柝聲 is the author. The original book is in Chinese. His English name is Watchman Nee.

Comment: +1 to recommending “Spiritual Man,” although because it is one of the densest - if not the densest - of Nee’s books, I’d recommend “A Normal Christian Life” or “Sit, Walk, Stand” as your first introduction to Nee :).

Comment: @Levan There is not a scripture in sight! Perhaps this was intended for the philosophy site?

Comment: @user48152 There is nothing in my answer that is not for and about this passage of the Scripture. Paul wrote in Greek an Hellenic culture and its philosophical notions and terms influenced, necessarily, also him; the ψυχή and πνεύμα distinction is one of them.

Comment: that maybe so, without relevant biblical references it is opinion based.

Comment: Biblical author (Paul, Like etc.) will never say: “I am using a Hellenic philosophic notion here or there”, you need a science for that, knowledge of the historical and philosophical-cultural setting of the epoch, for which you will find yourself necessitated to look also outside the Biblical text.

Comment: Anyhow, I have 0 care for downvotes and am thankful for your interest and reading my comment.

Comment: @user48152 That I haven't asked questions on this site does not mean I do not have them, but when I do have, I try to find on my own in theological literature or ask my own teachers and the experts in the field I know in person, with whom I have constant e-mail contact. As yet, it had worked. But I am very much interested in ideas of others, even when they contradict mine, and am thankful for their comments on my views, which can fall into error, for sure, for I am not a Pope of Rome to be infallible in doctrinal matters :) (joke, of course, for I do not believe in Papal infallibility).

Comment: @SteveTaylor We're not here for opinions though are we? That said, it is a popular occurrence even so and not uncommon for Levan. Not sure of your motive - are you part of his fan base, a groupie perhaps or disciple?

Comment: @SteveTaylor Sorry, Steve, my previous answer was meant to you. I am not an arrogant person, but, really, am a bit of timid to ask questions to the site, the questions for which I can try find answers with my own efforts and the literature and experts fortunately available to me. I know so many experts in the field of theology in person, have participated in number of international theological conferences, among them twice on Oxford Patristic conference that is held once per 4 years, and am blessed with relationship of the worlds greatest experts.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Yes, even such a super intellect as Plato will not be saved without Christ's sacrifice on Cross. Yet, Christ's birth was celebrated not only by the simple Bethlehem shepherds, but also by Babylonian mathematicians who traversed at a risk of their life 100s kilometres to give gifts and worship the Saviour, and also angels, who are unflappable intellects always contemplating divine glory. Philosophy was also blessed by Jesus and His divinity is also revealed by dialectics led by Holy Spirit. Unfortunately, many on this site close their intellectual eyes and deny to see the evident.

Comment: @SteveTaylor p.s. and as to voting: for me this site is a space for engaging in noblest ideas and problems of humanity and express my thoughts  I deem to be truthful, in sincerety of heart. up vote-down vote thing is a secondary or even hundrendary issue. When a person down votes somebody without explanation and argument, this can be a sing of wickedness and weakness (both closely related) of this person. I haven't down-voted anybody even once: if I disagree, I just write the reasons for my disagreement and that's it, why should I down-vote? But I gladly upwote good and instructive answers.

Comment: Again, if you're never asking questions and never downvoting, you're not using SE the way it is designed or intended to be used. I agree that this answer lacks a solid scriptural case and depends more heavily on philosophy than Hermeneutics for its conclusion. I down voted one other answer here for the same reason, left the other moderately Hermeneutics based answers alone and up voted another. We have to respond in all three ways for the system to work properly. The question is closed and will most likely be removed eventually, so chances are it won't change anything fairly soon.

Comment: @SteveTaylor SE system is SE system, could be better or worse, but if one down-votes without explanation, then most of the cases this is ignoble action, because if he does not explain the reasons for down-voting he leaves a down-voted person alone with his mistake, if there is mistake. But if there is no mistake really discerned and the guy down-votes, and anonymously, then this is both ignoble and cowardly thing. I do not think SE inventors would object me. And I just do not like to down-vote; why should I? If I find any, in my view, mistake, I give my counter arguments and this openly.